# DSL network connection problem in ubuntu

Tags: networking, dsl

In Ubuntu 10 How can I've access to internet through my DSL network.In windows7 I'vea network dialer, I just enter user name & password.In ubuntu I've created a dsl network ,In the add section I've entered username and password But worth nothing.I only have access to the network's internal website.

Comment: Visit this for my question which is similar
http://askubuntu.com/questions/288504/why-doesnt-my-pppoe-connection-connect-to-the-internet?noredirect=1#comment362568_288504

Answer (score 1):

use `sudo pppoeconf` after connecting the computer to the modem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to "**Edit connections...**"
2. In the "**Network Connections**" dialog box, click on the **DSL** tab.
3. Add a new DSL connection by clicking on "**Add**" button.

   In the "**Editing DSL Connection 1**" dialog box, fill in the required information.
4. Click on "**Wired**" tab.

   Here you specify you Ethernet card by clicking on drop down menu.
5. Click on "**Save**" and the new DSL connection is ready to use.