# Why doesn't my PPPoE connection connect to the internet?

Tags: internet, pppoe

I have a wired PPPOE connection (a wire comes straight from my windows and connects to CPU).

This is how I connect in WindowsXP dual boot:

[image]

```
$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:d0:e9:3b:67  
          inet6 addr: 2002:cab3:563b:4:21f:d0ff:fee9:3b67/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fec0::4:21f:d0ff:fee9:3b67/64 Scope:Site
      inet6 addr: fe80::21f:d0ff:fee9:3b67/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2002:cab3:563b:4:e8b4:6af0:2e4f:6792/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fec0::4:e8b4:6af0:2e4f:6792/64 Scope:Site
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:983 errors:0 dropped:17 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:110704 (110.7 KB)  TX bytes:8719 (8.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:10976 (10.9 KB)  TX bytes:10976 (10.9 KB)

$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:d0:e9:3b:67  
      inet6 addr: 2002:cab3:563b:4:21f:d0ff:fee9:3b67/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fec0::4:21f:d0ff:fee9:3b67/64 Scope:Site
      inet6 addr: fe80::21f:d0ff:fee9:3b67/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2002:cab3:563b:4:e8b4:6af0:2e4f:6792/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fec0::4:e8b4:6af0:2e4f:6792/64 Scope:Site
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:16096 errors:0 dropped:35 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2089011 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:78962 (78.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:15872 (15.8 KB)  TX bytes:15872 (15.8 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:111.125.231.234  P-t-P:202.179.72.226  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
      RX packets:668 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:633 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:502206 (502.2 KB)  TX bytes:50026 (50.0 KB)
```

Tried with `sudo pppoeconf` and put my password and username.

I tried wired connection and even DSL connection but nothing works. The funny thing was that when I try to call the internet provider they said: *"If you are using Linux you must able to solve the problem by yourself"*.

Somewhere I read that someone edited the `ppp.conf` file and put in `ACNAME=` then something like this `f10-suhar`. I don't know why but it has worked for him.

`sudo pppoeconf` connection has been set, but it keeps on opening a window with my username & password and asks to connect, but nothing connects.

Comment: Did you try to create it using Network Manager? See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/153030/114818

Comment: Aditya , tried that

Comment: no ppp.conf file is there in etc/ppp
but can other files are there

Comment: @Aditya  
i have PPPoE as mentioned above   
i tried "sudo pppoeconf" got connected but could not disconnect using poff.  

Also, after reboot i could not connect directly.   
"pon dsl-provider" also failed, ping 8.8.8.8 showed , "network was unreachable"   
So i tried "sudo pppoeconf" again n i was connected. Evey time i have to go through these clinches to connect. Any solution?

Comment: the key was `sudo pppoeconf` , but its not a good way to connect, .
connection often fails